# Consulta de último stock_fisico de mi tabla según el código de producto en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo la siguiente consulta a mi tabla:

```
select stkfisico from det_mov_almacen where Cod_producto = "1011020010001" order by stkfisico limit 1;
```

Obtengo como respuesta el penúltimo, y si pruebo con `asc` antes de `Limit` me sale igual, o si pruebo con `desc` me sale el primero.

Comment: si ordenas por stkfisico va a ordenar el valor de esos campos, no te lo va a traer como deseas.

Answer (score 0):

necesitas ordenar por otro campo, ya que DESC sólo ordenará en base a los valores de ese campo. lo más lógico sería que ordenaras en base al ID, suponiendo que sea numérico, o en base a una fecha si es que guardas alguna. Tu query sería algo así:

```
 SELECT  stkfisico from det_mov_almacen where Cod_producto = "1011020010001"  
ORDER BY ID_det_mov_almacen DESC  
LIMIT 1;
```